# Custom video player with custom controls - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

Is it possible to customize the AVPlayer or anything else for iOS view to eliminate the center play button and include your own graphics for play buttons and their location?  I am working on application that uses the Vimeo API to feed videos in the application and I would like to keep the thumbnail clean an avoid the center ugly gray button.

Can someone point me in the right direction of what I should be using to accomplish this?  I would like to have a play button towards the bottom or top left and then that will open the video full screen.

The application will be a scroll view with several videos each having this customization.

Thanks.

Comment: You need use AVPlayer with custom control.

Comment: Thanks @iOSWeblineindia - do you have any examples or documentation here?